# Use of derived class over the existing classes - Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Why do we need inheritance concept when we can simply instantiate another object in the existing class?
For example:
class Person
{
}
class Student extends Person
{
}

Here the class student and person possess IS-A relationship. But what is the need to define student class when we can add the same functionality to Person class?

Comment: Read the document and search about the details

Comment: Does the functionality belong to the Person class? For example: you could implement a learn() method inside the Person class, but does the functionality belong there?

Comment: A Teacher is a Person too, both have a birth date. Would you duplicate that field in both classes or put it just once in the Person class?

Comment: *"But what is the need to define student class when we can add the same functionality to Person class"* - you cant. A Student has a "University" for example, a Person does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is code reuse.

Imagine that we have also the following classes: Employee, Child, Manager, Student, etc. What if we wanted to add some functionalities that are common to all these classes, like: name, surname, birthdate? We would have to add it to every class in our code.

This is where class inheritance helps us reuse our code: 
1. We can create a class that is common to other classes. In this case a class called Person.
2. Make other classes (Employee, Student) inherit from this class

It has also other advantages. For instance, if we have a method that take an object of type Person, then it would work for objects whose class inherits from the class Person.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need the concept of inheritance?

You're practically asking the question *"Why bother with OOP when you can just code imperatively?"*

It really comes down to a matter of coding practice/paradigm choice and as @ammaro stated, in this specific scenario, by utilizing inheritance you are able to not only refactor your code in a much cleaner and more organized way, but also are following proper object-oriented programming practices by doing so.

Theoretics aside and in practice, the reason why that you would need to define the `Student` class is that *it has properties of and is based off the `Person` class, but it has other features that distinguishes it and thus should be created separately.*

Hope this helped!